# Xamarin Forms photo Pan/Scale/Crop plugin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, crop

I'm making app with using XF pcl.

To make photo viewer/editor function, you should add Pan/Scale/Crop.
Is there good plugin that somebody already have done for it?

Of course I can make my own but
It's very common behavior so I'm curious.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no plugin/component/NuGet for that. Go Nuts!

Comment: @MarioGalván Really!? That's sad!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this, this library has a lot of different transformations.
https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms/

Comment: Thank Patrick. Actually I know it and I want to choose more simple approuch.